# scraping a page that redirects

Tags: node.js, cheerio

i try to scrape a simple page (require cheerio and request):
https://www.ishares.com/uk/individual/en/products/251824/

The code fails. I believe it is because, in order to get to the above, users are prompted on previous page for "individual" or "institutional" so are being redirected.

I have tried different variations of the url, but all fail.

how can i get the raw HTML using node.js ?

here is the code:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');   // fast flexible implement of jQuery for server.
var fs = require('fs');

var app = express();
var port = 8000;
var timeLog = [];  // for dl to measure the time of events.

// var startTime = Date.now();


timeLog[0] = Date.now();
console.log('program initiated at time: '+new Date());


// example 1:  pull the webpage and print to console
var url ="https://www.ishares.com/uk/individual/en/products/251824/ishares-jp-morgan-emerging-markets-bond-ucits-etf";
url = "https://www.ishares.com/uk/individual/en/products/251824/";
url="https://www.ishares.com/uk/individual/en/products/251824/ishares-jp-morgan-emerging-markets-bond-ucits-etf?siteEntryPassthrough=true&locale=en_GB&userType=individual";


request(url,function functionName(err,resp,body) {
 var $ = cheerio.load(body);

 var distYield = $('.col-distYield');
 var distYieldText = distYield.text();
 console.log('we got to line 24');
 console.log(distYieldText);


 timeLog[2] = Date.now();
 console.log('data capture time: '+(timeLog[2] - timeLog[0])/1000+' seconds');

  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }else {
    //console.log(body);
    console.log('the body was written: success');
  }
});

// example 2:  download webpage and save file
var destination = fs.createWriteStream('./downloads/iSharesSEMB.html');
request(url)
  .pipe(destination);


// example 3:
var destination = fs.createWriteStream('./downloads/iSharesSEMB2.html');
request(url)
  .pipe(destination)
  .on("finish",function () {
    console.log('done');
  })
  .on('error',function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });



timeLog[1] = Date.now();
console.log('program completed at time: '+new Date());
console.log('Asynchronous program run time: '+(timeLog[1] - timeLog[0])/1000+' seconds');
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or just failing to scrape your wanted parts of the HTML ? what parts exactly do you want to scrape ?

Comment: Not getting an error. What actually happens is get the HTML for the first page and not the redirected page (after answering the question) which contains the info required (for example on that page, distribution yield).  Can see the output HTML here: var destination = fs.createWriteStream('./downloads/iSharesSEMB.html');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I got it to work. I enabled cookie support for `request` but then got into a redirect loop. Adding a promise worked it out. Here's only the relevant HTML request part:

```
const request = require('request'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio');


const url = "https://www.ishares.com/uk/individual/en/products/251824/ishares-jp-morgan-emerging-markets-bond-ucits-etf?siteEntryPassthrough=true&locale=en_GB&userType=individual";

options = {
    jar: true
}

const getDistYield = url => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(url, options, function(err,resp,body) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            let $ = cheerio.load(body);
            resolve($('.col-distYield'));
        })
    })
}

getDistYield(url)
    .then((tag) => {
        console.log(tag.text())
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.error(e)
    })
```

Outputs:

> Distribution Yield
>   The distribution yield represents the ratio of distributed income over the last 12 months to the fund’s current NAV.
>   as of 20-Feb-2018
>   4.82

Also, notice I've used the last URL you provided.

I hope this works it out for you :)

Comment: Thank you. This works. I note that you have added as the 2nd param in the request() function.... 'options = {
    jar: true
}'   is this how one enables cookie support ?

Comment: @D.L that is correct. You’ll find a list of all available options in the request npm page. https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#requestoptions-callback

Comment: If the user needs to extract just the value which appears to be a class inside a class, how would they do this ?  so in this case, just the 4.82 (and not the rest of the text).

Answer (score 0):

have amended the resolve part to just get the value (and not the text) which is a nested class.

```
resolve($('.col-distYield > span:nth-child(2)'));
```