# Make axios wait for redirection

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, cheerio

I'm trying to scrape data from google map using the /search/ from maps.

When I search it myself, I tape this:
'https://www.google.com/maps/search/new york'

And then I'm redirected to this url: 
'https://www.google.com/maps/place/New+York,+%C3%89tat+de+New+York,+%C3%89tats-Unis/@40.6974881,-73.979681,10z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c24fa5d33f083b:0xc80b8f06e177fe62!8m2!3d40.7127753!4d-74.0059728'

I can't manage to reproduce this behavior using axios. I guess there's maybe something to make with async / await but i didn't find any solution since then.

here's my code :

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

var map = 'www.google.com/maps/search/';

axios.get(map + 'New York')
    .then(response => {
        let getData = html => {
            coor = [];
            v= -1;
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);
            $('.widget-pane-content scrollable-y').each((i, elem) => {
                coor.push({
                    adress : $(elem).find('span.widget-pane-link').text(),
                });
            });
            console.log(coor);
            console.log(coor.length);
        }
        getData(response.coor);
    })
    .catch(error => {console.log(error);})
```

When I execute the file, I get this error:

```
'Error: Request failed with status code 400'
```

If you have any clue to solve my problem, thanks for sharing it!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Since most of the elements are injected via JS, cheerio and axios can't really do much. I'd try something like Puppeteer or Selenium.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah i already used puppeteer before, but with many request the execution will take years isn't it?

Comment: How many requests are you making? Yes, these tools are super slow, but unless you can find an API to hit (like [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation)), there might not be many other options.

Comment: a few thousand, and i never used an API before, i'm afraid of loosing lot of time :/ i'm in a rush tho

Comment: Then the API is your best option, I'd think. Scraping the data to avoid the API is going to be more work and time in the long run.

Comment: What are you scraping from that page?

Comment: There shouldn't be a space in that url, try replacing with %20

Answer (score 0):

Look into a tool like Selenium, or Cypress.js (a wrapper around selenium)

(search "end to end testing" or "automated browser")

This unfortunately cannot be done with a tool like Axios.  Google Maps doesn't return a `redirect` response, but rather uses JavaScript to reload the page.

example with cypress:

```js
cy.visit("https://www.google.com/maps/search/new york");
cy.wait(2000);  // sit for 2 seconds
cy.get('#thing-im-looking-for')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! But unfortunately i think it won't make it, since i have to do it for at least 7000 request, so it would take more than 3 hours for it to run

Comment: assuming this is for "professional" / "production" code, you may want to look into requesting this from the paid google API @CanardWcs

Comment: Yes, was looking to it, thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

Try using cookieJar with axios

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/943#issuecomment-599174929

Or set jar to true with `request` package

```
 request(url, { jar: true })
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48912841/11686526

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30982459)